# Jquery - How to remove an element from a div and update that div to the remaining elements

Tags: jquery, html, height

How to remove an element from a div and update that div height to the remaining elements ?

So the problem is that i can delete the elements inside the div when i click on them, but then i am left with the spaces of the removed elements, any help ?

i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('#content').css("height", "auto");
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing a dollar sign

Comment: just here, but still not working

Comment: If the height is auto, it should update automagically once elements are removed, if it isn't, you'll have to recreate the problem in a fiddle so we can actually see it.

Comment: I think the problem is very explicit, if there where no jsfidlle would you guys not help ?

Comment: "So the problem is that i can delete the elements inside the div when i click on them, but then i am left with the spaces of the removed elements, any help ?" if i remove for example table 3 it just desapears but the div #content remains its height

Comment: ok i just tried with another div inside #content and $('#content').css("height", "auto"); was "called" but it didnt wrap to the elements

Answer (score 0):

Place the `height` call outside of the `click` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').css("height", "auto");
    $("table").click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't work, seem's like the problem is with $('#content').css("height", "auto");

Comment: i just tried with a div that is not originally set with width and height and position absolute

Comment: @FábioLinhares did you try setting the `#content` DIV's height to auto in your CSS? Not in jQuery...

Comment: @FábioLinhares try doing that! :-)

Comment: could it be because the tables como from php loop ?